# Bash | Host-check

Tags: bash

I have a little problem with my bash script
i got a school project where i have to make a bash script to check if the host is up every 5 minuttes and if fails send email

i had problems with the "fi" statement but fixed the error.
now when i run the script i get an error: line 17 to many arguments"
it initiate the ping command (my Anti virus is blocking the ICMP, so i know the ping lines work)

```
#!/bin/bash

#Server-status script

FAILS=0
EMAIL_ADDRESS="Critical-error@gruppe4.net" ##Email capabilities 
SERVER="192.168.1.1"  ###Host to check
SLEEP=300           ###Defining Sleep

while true; do
ping -c 1 $SERVER >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then #if ping exits nonzero...
    FAILS=$"[FAILS + 1]"
else
    FAILS=0
fi
if [ $FAILS -gt 4 ]; then
    FAILS=0
    echo "Server $SERVER is offline!" \
        | mail -s "Server offline" "$EMAIL_ADDRESS"
fi
sleep $SLEEP #check again in SLEEP seconds
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `declare -i` to use FAILS as integer and initialize to 0

```
declare -i FAILS=0
```

then sum 1

```
FAILS=$FAILS+1
```

here is my code(I've commented the mail commmand):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Server-status script

declare -i FAILS=0
EMAIL_ADDRESS="Critical-error@gruppe4.net" ##Email capabilities 
SERVER="192.168.1.1"  ###Host to check
SLEEP=1           ###Defining Sleep

echo "1-FAILS[$FAILS]"

while true; do
   ping -c 1 $SERVER >/dev/null 2>&1
   if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then #if ping exits nonzero...
       FAILS=$FAILS+1 
   else
       FAILS=0
   fi

   echo "2-FAILS[$FAILS]"

   if [ $FAILS -gt 1 ]; then
       FAILS=0
       echo "Server $SERVER is offline!" # \ | mail -s "Server offline"   "$EMAIL_ADDRESS"
   fi
       sleep $SLEEP #check again in SLEEP seconds
done
```

output:

```
sh-4.3$ bash -f main.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  1-FAILS[0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  2-FAILS[1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  2-FAILS[2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Server 192.168.1.1 is offline!                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  2-FAILS[1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  2-FAILS[2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Server 192.168.1.1 is offline!                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  2-FAILS[1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  2-FAILS[2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Server 192.168.1.1 is offline!                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  2-FAILS[1]
```

I hope this can help

Regards
Claudio

Comment: This one did the job
Many thanks 

Best regards 
Jan poulsen

Answer (score 0):

You are expanding the `$FAILS` variable with content `[FAILS + 1]`, getting an invalid `[]` syntax.

Change `FAILS=$"[FAILS + 1]"` to:

```
FAILS=$((FAILS+1))
```